# Application get crash in Ipad when camera is called second time in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, plugin.media.crossmedia

I am using a camera on button click, but when user press the button second time the application get crashed. This is only happening on Ipad, its working smoothly on Iphone and android phones. I am using below code to initiate the camera.

```
                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
                    return;
                }


                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Small,
                    DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
                    Directory = "Sample",
                    Name = "test.jpg"
                });

                if (file == null)
                    return;

                var lStream = file.GetStream();
```

Comment: what exception causes the crash?  what is the stack trace?

Comment: You should share the error message or device log so that we can help you better. And I found an open issue [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/696)

Comment: yes this is same thing happening with me, it just crashes the application on TakePhotoAsync and doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Then you should follow that issue link to get the latest information.

Comment: But no one has responded after that, have you tried something similar?

Comment: No, I did not test it on ipad. It's a third-part library and if you can share any error log or stacktrace here, maybe we can help you.